Swap out a stopped process' memory to swap file
I want to move the resident/virtual data of a SIGSTOPped process out of main memory and into any suitable swap. With the ability to revert the procedure before SIGCONTinuing the process.
The system does not have a dedicated swap space because normally I don't want things to be swapped. So a solution that writes to a dedicated file in a filesystem of my choice would be preferable. So, possibly "swap" is not entirely the correct word here, but if all else fails, a temporary swap space could be established.
Context: A program that takes a long time to start and wind down and is used intermittently uses not only a significant amount of cpu time while idle but also uses 60-80% of the system's memory. STOP/CONT works well to drop idle spinning, and even survives system suspends without problem, but while stopped, the system's memory effectively is reduced to 20-40%.
Using Linux' normal swapping behaviour a) makes it necessary to have a swap space that is normally not used outside of this particular scenario and more importantly b) is unreliable with regard to when it swaps out what. The wrong process might be swapped out or at a moment where it is inconvenient. Instead I have an SSD that can more than accommodate the resident set of the process, even the virtual set. And I want to control when or whether or not the swapping is to occur.

Possible approaches.

This serverfault answer suggests madvise but there is no clear way to revert the procedure seeing as there is no counterpart to MADV_PAGEOUT.
Setting a specific file as swap for a process appears to be possible as per Have a private swap file per process.



The system does not have a dedicated swap space because normally I don't want things to be swapped. So a solution that writes to a dedicated file in a filesystem of my choice would be preferable. So, possibly "swap" is not entirely the correct word here, but if all else fails, a temporary swap space could be established.

yeah, swap is a system-wide thing :) And, to the best of my knowledge, you can't force a single process's virtual memory to be swapped out; a stopped process would be quite high up the list of things to swap, though, so setting up a temporary swap space, and increasing the swappiness (sudo sysctl -w vm.swappiness=100), then increasing memory pressure (like by yes | head -c 1G /tmp/tmpfile, assuming /tmp is a tmpfs mount) would probably swap out the process.
But frankly, your use case sounds 100% like CRIU, "Checkpoint / Restore in Userspace". That's a mature technology that allows you to just take the state of a program, save it to storage, and get it back later.
Naturally, that would require that none of the other things that program interacted with haven't changed in unexpectable ways (network connections, for example, can break at any point, anyways, so most programs would be robust against that, but no program would expect their database file to be changed while they were "put in a can").
There's a rather easy, and common, solution to that, and it comes with a few additional benefits in your situation: Containers.
The additional benefits would be being able to trivially limit the percentage of non-idle CPU time the program can take, the RAM and the disk IO rates and such; container runtimes typically put their containers in cgroup scopes that allow you to specify such limits.
I use podman for containers; podman has CRIU-based store/restore built in.
# run in background
podman run -d --name resourcehog debian:12 sh -c 'apt update; apt install -y stress -c8'

# store state to disk, stop running
podman container checkpoint --create-image resourcehog-frozen-as-hell resourcehog

# later, restore
podman container restore --name resourcehog-continuation resourcehog-frozen-as-hell

Instead of --create-image, you can also --export to a tar.gz file (it will in my experience be slower to export), and then --import the same file on restore.

That's an interesting suggestion. But it would require me to set up a container environment for the process, right? Or can just run a binary as if it ran on the host directly? It's been a while since I used docker, sorry.

no need for docker, I'd recommend podman (see above), luckily compatible in most ways. Yep, it would require you to put that application in a container; I found that not very hard (but everyone's different). For quick "one off" things, I just start a temporary interactive container with the OS of my choice (e.g., podman run -it --rm fedora:40), download, build and install things in there, clean up in there as I would from any other command line, then from a separate shell, podman commit to a new image, which then is just the readily set up base image. I can then …

… run things like podman run -v /home/me/my/data:/data:Z  myimagename executablename to start exactly what I want. For things than need to be reproducible, I, instead of starting a temporary container, write a Dockerfile script, which does all the installation steps.
